# Partial limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus, limits

In my assignment I have to find all the **partial limits** of the following sequence:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(-5)^n-2^n+2}{3^n+(-2)^n-2}$$

I wanted to seperate this question to $n$ elements that are even, and odd.

I started with the even ones, and I wanted to know:

- If my solution is correct.
- If I can use limit arithmetic to solve this question (again, seperating the odd n from the even n, because the whole sequence is not convergent).
- Assuming n is even, take $5^n$ outside of the brackets and get the following:
- $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(-5)^n(\frac{1-\frac{2^n}{(-5)^n}+\frac{2}{(-5)^n}}{3^n+(-2)^n-2})$$
- $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (-5)^n = \infty$$
- $$(\frac{1-\frac{2^n}{(-5)^n}+\frac{2}{(-5)^n}}{3^n+(-2)^n-2}) >0$$ (I don't think it's hard to prove)

Therefore, by the rule $\infty *$ positive number = $\infty$ I can say that $\infty$ is a partial limit of the original sequence.

Is my solution correct? I didn't try it yet for odd numbers.

Also, can I use limit arithmetic here? I mean, for the odd and even seperation, they have limits as we can see.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your method, write

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-5)^n-2^n+2}{3^n+(-2)^n-2}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(-5)^n}{3^n}\frac{1-(-2/5)^n+2(1/5)^n}{1+(-2/3)^n-2(1/3)^n}$$

Now, we know that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1-(-2/5)^n+2(1/5)^n}{1+(-2/3)^n-2(1/3)^n} =1$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left|\frac{(-5)^n}{3^n}\right| = \infty$$

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use limit arithmetic here?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  In general, you cannot write $\lim a_n b_n =\lim a_n \lim b_n$  when either $a_n$ or $b_n$ diverges.